# "Error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)) : missing values in object" when using acf function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to simulate a basic moving average process in R:

> x_t = Z_(t-1)-0.4Z_(t-2)+Z_t.

My code is:

```
z = rnorm(500, 0, 1)
x = filter(z, sides=2, filter = c(1, 1, -.4), method="convolution")
acf(x)
```

When the

```
acf(x)
```

function is used I receive the following error

```
Error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)) : missing values in object
```

This worked perfectly when I simulated the following with an autoregressive process AR(1)

> x_t = .9*x_{t-1} + W_t

with the following code

```
w = rnorm(550, 0,1)  
x = filter(w, filter=c(0.9), method="recursive")
acf(x)
```

I am pretty confused as to what I could be missing. Does anyone know how I am to fix this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
x = filter(z, sides=2, filter = c(1, 1, -.4), method="convolution")
```

the default for the option  `circular = FALSE` have missing values at the ends of `x`.

So, either you have to remove the ends of `x` (`acf(x[-c(1, 500)]`), or use `circular = TRUE` option in the filter.

From the help

> circular: for convolution filters only.  If 'TRUE', wrap the filter
>             around the ends of the series, otherwise assume external
>             values are missing ('NA').